# Are there any symptoms of Vitamin D deficiency?

Tags: micronutrients, milk, deficiency, melanin, vitamin-d

I've heard that Vitamin D is mainly obtained from the sun or you have to take supplements. Getting it from the sun also depends on many factors, such as the latitude, time of the day, skin color, area exposed etc.

I am a office worker with light brown skin. I walk in the sun for around 10-15 minutes a day which I think is insufficient. I do not take any Vitamin D supplements, as well. I am a vegetarian, but do drink milk (not fortified with Vitamin D, though) and other milk products.

I am afraid I might have Vitamin D deficiency, but am not sure. Is there any symptom associated with Vitamin D deficiency? Or would this deficiency only be determined only by a test?

I could not find a reliable source of information on the web.

Comment: I am no doctor, but although I did some research about this topic some time ago, I did never really find out about clear and early symptoms. If I was you, I'd better visit my physician and ask him/her for a blood test.

Comment: @ByteCommander, yeah I would consult doctor but wanted to seek suggestions here first.

Comment: You will be surprised how low that vitamin D rate can be. It's usually three times lower than you would expect it to be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/vitamin-d-deficiency)

Signs and Symptoms of Vitamin D deficiency can be subtle, but can manifest as bone pain and muscle weakness.  Also, [excessive sweating](http://www.prevention.com/health/symptoms-vitamin-d-deficiency)(when not indicated due to exercise level and heat).

Because of the sometimes subtle symptoms, getting appropiate screening based on risk factors and regular physician exams is important to discovering and managing deficiency.

[Tests for Vitamin D Deficiency](http://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/vitamin-d-deficiency?page=2)

> The most accurate way to measure how much vitamin D is in your body is
>   the 25-hydroxy vitamin D blood test. A level of 20
>   nanograms/milliliter to 50 ng/mL is considered adequate for healthy
>   people. A level less than 12 ng/mL indicates vitamin D deficiency.

[7 Signs You May Have a Vitamin D Deficiency](http://articles.mercola.com/sites/articles/archive/2014/05/28/vitamin-d-deficiency-signs-symptoms.aspx) can help in the you understand risk factors, because knowing risk factors can mean better  understanding to what symptoms may mean.

Treatment is diet with adequate Vitamin D and supplements. While treatment may be simple, prolonged deficiency can manifest as very serious manifestations so if worried about deficiency a Vitamin D test and Physician Workup is indicated.

---

Risk Factors:

[Include:](http://www.webmd.com/diet/guide/vitamin-d-deficiency) Allegy to milk, vegan diets, darker skin and amount of sun you recieve.

Answer (score 1):

Vitamin D deficiency can actually cause or exacerbate depression, and it can manifest itself in feelings of tiredness, persistent sadness, weakness, etc... It also prevents your bones from mineralizing so your bone density may decline and cause bone pain (as stated by WebMD). I've experienced this, and it feels like an ache deep inside your limbs. I also had pretty strong dairy cravings, which I think may have been  However, sometimes these symptoms are slight and you may not even know you have a deficiency. I came to the doctor once with complaints of depression and tiredness. She ordered a blood test for a bunch of things, including blood iron levels and vitamin D levels. My iron levels were good but my vit D was low, and I never would have guessed; I thought I was depressed and just needed antidepressants.

Definitely get a blood test for it if you're concerned because the symptoms of vitamin D deficiency can be attributed to so many different causes, and you may feel pretty "ok" when you could be feeling much better.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE. Links would better support your answer. For reference see the Help Center. Thanks.